# Access UI components in QT by entering the name of the component?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a lot of `ui` components in my `.ui` file.

They have a similar name e.g `analogRead0`, `analogRead1`, `analogRead2` and they have the same data type.

Is it possible for me to acces these fields inside the `.ui` file by using only the name?

I was thinking of I can make an instance of an object by just entering the name of the object, and not the class. Is that possible in `QT`?

For example, instead of writing

```
DoubleSpinBox *mySpinBox0 = ui->analogDifferentialInput0MaxDoubleSpinBox;
DoubleSpinBox *mySpinBox1 = ui->analogDifferentialInput1MaxDoubleSpinBox;
DoubleSpinBox *mySpinBox2 = ui->analogDifferentialInput2MaxDoubleSpinBox;
DoubleSpinBox *mySpinBox3 = ui->analogDifferentialInput3MaxDoubleSpinBox;
..
..
..
DoubleSpinBox *mySpinBoxN = ui->analogDifferentialInputNMaxDoubleSpinBox;
```

I can access all these `DoubleSpinBoxes` by entering the name `analogDifferentialInput` + a number + `MaxDoubleSpinBox`?

Comment: Wait a second... I'm looking at the problem wrong. What you want is an array! Just about every time you have a list of sequentially named or numbered variables your code will be much simpler with an array.

Comment: @user4581301 I understand. I insert them all into an array. But I have still write code for inserting all these objects into an array? I was hoping for if I could just use ObjectMeta or something like that?

Comment: Take a look at https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChild.

Comment: @scopchanov Yes that works! But it does not work for all C++ classes.

Comment: Hack: `#define MAX_DOUBLE_SPINBOX(num) ui->analogDifferentialInput##num##MaxDoubleSpinBox`

Comment: The problem with the general case: identifiers are compile-time information. The CPU doesn't need them. It just wants addresses and offsets from addresses, so those names are gone at runtime. QT is performing some runtime tricks to dig through its metadata, but those tricks only work with QT components that support and provide that metadata.

Comment: @user4581301 I don't understand. I understand the #define hack. But what if I have a regular C++ QT class. Can I find the children there as well I can do with a ``QWidget` class?

Comment: QT is doing work behind the scenes registering those objects when you make them. `std::string`, for example, has no such registry because building one takes time and having one consumes storage. C++ does (almost) nothing that you do not explicitly ask for if it has a runtime cost that isn't absolutely necessary for the majority of users.

Comment: @user4581301 So I cannot find the e.g methods, fields and etc. from a regular QT class that has `Q_OBJECT` macro, by using `findChildren`?

Comment: I can't speak for how far `Q_OBJECT` goes in providing support, but it should be documented.

Comment: @user4581301 So how would you do if you want to access a method by using a string?

Comment: Note that `ui_*` class is not a `QObject`. However, you can use QRegularExpression overload of `findChildren` on `this`. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChildren-2

Comment: @user4581301 `#define` is probably the best way to do, right?

Comment: Depends on exactly what you want to do with it. `#define` only works if everything is known at compile time. You can't simply pop that in a loop. If I had to look up things by name I'd do something similar to the array: pop everything into a `std::unordered_map<std::string, whatever>`.

Comment: @user4581301 Do you think this is a good idea `#define SET_ANALOG_DIFFERENTIAL_INPUT_MAX_VALUE(num) iOcalibration.setAnalogDifferentialInput##num##Max(iOCalibration.ui->analogDifferentialInput##num##MaxDoubleSpinBox->value())
`

Comment: Looks about right, but more of a get than a set.

Comment: @user4581301 I need to insert values from `ui` components into a specific class. Then I'm going to save that class as a file. Probably casting it to `uint8_t`.

Comment: @MrYui the title says _Access UI components in QT_. In Qt the ui components are `QWidget`s, resp. `QObject`s.

Comment: @scopchanov Yes. But my end goal is to insert values into an object.

Comment: What difference does that make?

Comment: @scopchanov Because I cannot save a complete object e.g `ui` to a file, then load it again.

Comment: I think your question is stated clearly and the link I have provided is the answer. There is nothing about saving and loading in the original post. Please try to formulate your exact problem as precise as it could get. You have already a huge discussion in the comments and that is usually a sign, that you ask something, yet you need something else, i.e. - a XY problem.

Comment: @scopchanov Yes! I will do that! Give me some time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the *object name* of the element in the `Designer`, then you can directly access them via [findChild](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChild) (once you have set up the `ui`...)

Here is an example, where I change the text for my 3 `QPushButton`s

```
ui->setupUi(this);

for(int i = 1; i <= 3; ++i){
  auto btn = findChild<QPushButton*>("button"+QString::number(i));

  if(btn)
      btn->setText("newName"+QString::number(i));
}
```

Comment: Does this work with regular classes as well in QT?

Comment: It only works with classes that are inherited from QObject.